# How to disable celery tasks while testing on django

Tags: django, django-celery, celery-task

Im trying to test some functions that include a call for celery tasks. the tasks involves a call to 3rd party websites and i need to avoid it during tests.

Any idea how to disable all celery tasks during tests?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually the "good method" imply doing Mocks.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

So you'll return example response from the site.

You can check on class declaration debug state and if True replace the class by the corresponding Mock

Answer (score 10):

You can patch the Task delay function

```
   patch("celery.app.task.Task.delay", return_value=1)
   patch("celery.app.task.Task.apply_async", return_value=1)
```

If you are using pytest, you can add this in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_celery_delay(mocker):
    mocker.patch("celery.app.task.Task.delay", return_value=1)
    mocker.patch("celery.app.task.Task.apply_async", return_value=1)
```

Comment: I ended up doing the same. This solution not only avoids the task running but also removes the need for a celery broker running. Note that delay calls apply_sync so no need to patch delay.